# Three.js local and global coordinates

Tags: three.js

Is there a function in the Three.js that converts local coordinates to/from global coordinates?  I understand the mathematics behind it but I would rather use a function from Three.js if it is available.

Comment: I typically write a prototype that traverses an object's parents until it hits the root scene. Did you find out if something like that already exists? (I realize this was almost 10 yrs ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1752

and check out the most recent development build (v.50).